# How about I don't want to output to nuhup.out file in gunicorn

Tags: gunicorn

I am running my script with gunicorn in background like this:
nohup gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:12345 CryptoDepth:app.server&

It would produce log file in nohup.out. However I don't want this since it exhaust my disk. Anyone knows how to do without any output? thanks.

Comment: how about moving stdout explicitly to /dev/null (by >). and stderr too (by 2>&1)

Comment: Yes that's working: nohup gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:12345 CryptoDepth:app.server& > /dev/null  2>&1